# ngClass OR expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element with ng-class attribute like this:

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label"
              ng-class="{'has-errors':{{loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$invalid}} || {{loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='err'}},
                         'no-errors':{{loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid}} || {{loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='ok'}}">
</label>
```

But classes aren't applying. What I did wrong and what is the best way to write an expressions like this?

Comment: you are putting expressions inside expressions, you should be able to remove the `{{}}`s

Comment: you don't need to use {{}} expression in ng-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write JavaScript expression inside ng-class. You don't need more braces `{{}}`:

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label"
              ng-class="{'has-errors':(loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$invalid) || (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='err'),
                         'no-errors':(loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid) || (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='ok')">
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have posted will work once you remove the `curly braces {{}}`. Logical operators are allowed within ng-class. But the better way would be to create a function and make that function return either true or false on the number on conditions that you want to test and then call that function from ng-class.

```
<label ng-class="{'classOne':check(), 'classTwo': checkAgain()}"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) ng-class already expect expression:

`<ANY ng-class="expression">`

You don't have to use '{{expression}}' syntax inside it. Try:

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label"
       ng-class="{'has-errors': (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$invalid) || (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='err'),
                  'no-errors': (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid) || (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='ok')">
</label>
```

But it is really hard to read, so maybe more preferable way is to create function inside of $scope:

```
$scope.hasErrors = function(loginForm, success) {
    return (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$invalid) || (loginForm.$submitted && loginForm['AccountLoginForm[username]'].$valid && success.data.login=='err')
}
```

And then refactor html code:

```
 <label class="item item-input item-floating-label"
       ng-class="{'has-errors': hasErrors(loginForm, success), 'no-errors': !hasErrors(loginForm, success)}">
</label>
```

Note that loginForm and success should exist in your current $scope. Hope it helps.